# Create buttons from text file

Tags: arrays, vb.net

I am using Visual Basic in Visual Studio 2017. I am trying to create buttons from a text file. If a text file contains words like 
Test1
Test2
Test3
etc it should create 3 buttons using those names.

```
Dim path As String = "c:\words.txt"

   Dim readText() As String = File.ReadAllLines(path)
   Dim s As String
    Dim button As New System.Windows.Forms.Button()
    Dim buttonTop As Integer = 100

    For Each s In readText
       Dim Location As New Point(100, (buttonTop + 20))
        button.Location = Location
        button.Text = s
        button.Width = 100
       Me.Controls.Add(button)
      buttonTop += 20
     button.Visible = True
Next
```

This code creates the buttons but are not saved. As the loop goes it creates them and they disappear from the form leaving just the last one at the end of the loop.
Any guidelines will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Put your New Button logic inside the loop.

Comment: `buttonTop += 20` doesnt not work in VBA.

Comment: @braX : Neither does the `System.Windows.Forms` namespace and a lot of other things. This isn't VBA, but VB.NET. It is a common mistake for newer users to mis-tag questions.

Answer (score 1):

Correct Answer. Thanks

```
Dim path As String = "c:\words.txt"

    Dim readText() As String = File.ReadAllLines(path)
    Dim s As String

    Dim buttonTop As Integer = 20


    For Each s In readText

        Dim button As New System.Windows.Forms.Button()

        Dim Location As New Point(100, (buttonTop + 30))
        button.Location = Location
        Button.Text = s
        button.Width = 100
        button.Height = 30
        Me.Controls.Add(Button)
        buttonTop += 30
        button.Visible = True
    Next
```